Icon handler Not working properly that newly sync or download files on Local onedrive folder
I made a dll file, and registering it.
dll implementing Icon Handler using IExtractIcon class.
Icon handler changes specific extension files icon.
It works well on common local folder.
on local onedrive folder, file icons are not correctly display.
when file is download, it not query icon.
but rename it then query icon and display changed icon.
[used and tried other ways]
I Forced emiting shell event using SHChangeNotify to onedrive folder.
then icon displayed correctly.
using ReIconCache or manually rebuild iconcache.db, refresh or restrat explorer.exe
then icon displayed correctly too.
but it's not solution of prob.
if anyone get simmilar problem?
+
implementing icon handler
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-icon-handlers

There is a similar question, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1518657/implementing-the-ishelliconoverlayidentifier-inter, I encounter but it is about cloud folders created by a cloud filter. I suspect It works by desktop4:DesktopIconOverlayHandlers.

that using overlayhandler, not icon handler. ther is some diffrent..
but thanks!

Yes, the icon handler will not be called if there's no file data locally (when the file is marked as "Available when online"). In this case, thumbnails are provided by Onedrive server and it doesn't know your local handler. Once the file is locally hydrated ("Available on this device") then the handler is called. After that the icon will be cached. I have not tested but it's possible it works if the .dll is packaged with an identity. Otherwise you can add OneDrive file handlers (server-side) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/?view=odsp-graph-online

adding the onedrive file handler will affect local folder's file icon? i'll try that.
"Once the file is locally hydrated ("Available on this device") then the handler is called. After that the icon will be cached. I have not tested but it's possible it works"
yes, but icon still not changed until rename it or rebuild iconcache. once cached, it remained changed icon even no file data locally.
i confuse this action.. :(
